# Finding the maximum element in the $n$th power of the transition matrix $A$ for $d$-regular digraph without computing $A^n$.

Tags: matrices, algorithms, random-walk

The transition matrix for a $d$-regular digraph (with no multi-edges but can have self-loops) is a matrix with $d$ non-zero entries of values $\frac{1}{d}$ in each row.

Given such an $m \times m$ matrix $A$, we would like to find the set of the maximum values in $A^n$ for all positive $n$. Suppose the size of the distinct values in that set is $r$. It is possible that $r$ is infinite. Our algorithm should be able to detect this case as well.

Does there exist an algorithm that runs in time $O(poly(d,m,r))$ that outputs the values of the maximum elements in $A^n$ for all $n$?

We would really want to make the running time independent from $n$. The usual $n$th power of matrix algorithm is overkill.

To make things more clear:

Let the max value of $A^i$ be $m_i$. We want the result set $S$ to consist of all pairs of $(i,m_i)$ such that all $m_i$ are distinct and only the minimum $i$ associated with $m_i$ is kept.

**Update: Since the value of $A^n$ is infeasible in general. We save the index pair of $(r,c)$ where $A^n[r,c]$ is the maximum for step $n$. $S$ consists of $(i,r,c)$ triplets.**

Comment: Well, you can get the entire $A^n$ using diagonalization or more generally the Jordan normal form, and it will technically be in that complexity class, provided some small error is tolerable. This is probably not in the spirit of what you want here though.

Comment: Well the point is we only want the maximum. The diagonalization might be overkill too.

Comment: Well, if this isn't OK then you need to reframe your criteria, I think. Because this does satisfy your independence of $n$ requirement.

Comment: I believe that the spectrum approaches would not give you pairs of exact $(i, m_i)$.

Comment: Using numerical diagonalization, the $m_i$ isn't exact, that is true. But then, multiplying $A^n$ out on a computer would generally not be exact either, unless you do it in rational number arithmetic. The $i$ you get is "probably" exact, provided that there is an appreciable gap from the value at the argmax to the value at the next index down.

Comment: Can you describe your diagonalization procedure in an algorithmic way or link me to some resources that I can look up? I feel that since there is a gap between mixing time and relaxation time the index of $i$ can never be solved exactly unless we perform the traditional way of sparse matrix multiplication. For example, we just sum up all values per iteration that are from the incoming edges.

Comment: Considering the difficulty of storing the maximum value accurately, saving which entry $(i,j)$ might be more feasible.

Comment: $A=P D P^{-1}$ and then $A^n = P D^n P^{-1}$, then multiply those out. $D^n$ just involves exponentiation of scalars so it is $O(m \log(n))$ if you use exponentation by squaring, or even less dependence on $n$ than that if you use $a^n = \exp(n \log(a))$.

Comment: How do you get $P$ accurately? $D$ will contain complex numbers too especially since this is a transition matrix for a $d$-regular digraph.

Comment: Just updated the question so now we only care about where one of those maximums is located.

Comment: Finding $P$ and $D$ accurately is routine with a variety of eigendecomposition algorithms. Though you didn't say how big $m$ is, so this may be unrealistic to begin with. From what you were saying, it seemed like the interest was in $n \gg m$.

Comment: The $m$ is huge but quite inductive. The graph is a product of a family of graphs. I am trying to prove for some family of graphs the product graph has a maximum of some asymptotics for random walks of length of every $n$. In order to make my proof work, I need some constructive algorithm first. The interest on the contrary is to see when the maximum is guaranteed to reach $\frac{1}{d^n}$ when I induce the family of graphs.